# Predict on batch returns only one output

Tags: keras, tf.keras

Whether I call my predict_on_batch on my model with 1 sample or 5, I always recieve output of the same shape
I thought if the output shape of one sample is (a,b) then predict_on_batch would return output of shape (batch_size,a,b)

```
print(input_batch.shape) # (1,416,416,3)
output = model.predict_on_batch(input_batch)
print(type(output)) # list
print(len(output)) # 2
print(input_batch.shape) # (5,416,416,3)
print(type(output)) # list
print(len(output)) # 2
```

My model input tensor is tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,None,3))
Each input sample is an image with shape (416,416,3)

Model body: https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/yolo3/model.py#L89

Comment: You should provide code and evidence of this problem. Maybe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: hey , I added some code examples, hopefully this helps

Comment: Does your model have two outputs? Again, more code like the model.

Comment: Yes, this is the model body: https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/yolo3/model.py#L89

Comment: You should understand how keras makes the output for a multi-output model, as you have two output heads, each of them will be a batch of samples. There is nothing wrong here, just incorrect interpretation.

Comment: Yes I presume I am getting a list of two tensors - each from one of the output layers. I pass the list of tensors through - https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/yolo3/model.py#L187 to get the output of bboxes, scores and classes where each one of them has size 20
No matter the input batch size, the output of bboxes, scores and classes has size of 20 elements

Comment: I thought I should be getting batch_size number of list of two tensors - one for every sample in my batch_size

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I am misinterpreting the results, thanks @Dr.Snoopy 
I am trying to get batch_size number of (list of 2 output tensors from each of my output layers) so I can differentiate which input image is the list of output tensors for

Comment: batch size does not change the output size of the network (this is given by how many images you input to predict), only how many samples are processed at a time.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.Snoopy, how do I decide that what portion of the output tensors are for which  input sample since I am only getting two output tensors for any number of samples

Comment: Again, your model has two outputs, this is fixed, output[0] and output[1] each contain inside all the samples you predicted, just print output[0].shape and output[1].shape

Comment: Oh my god, youre my hero @Dr.Snoopy